# What are these tools used for?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

I have recently found in a box these two tools:

[image: Tool Set 1]

[image: Tool 2]

I do not have any knowledge on whether these tools are for wood or metal.
The second tool can be winded and unwinded in order to form some kind of tooth bite like shape to a material.

Many thanks on the feedback.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The top tools appear to be dies - used for cutting screw threads on rods.  The lower tool appears to be a tap wrench (a tap is a tool a little like a drill bit, but used for cutting threads inside a hole).  The "winding and unwinding" action is to allow it to clamp to the tap; the wrench is then used to turn the tap in the hole.  The dies would also have had a wrench or handle with which to grip and turn them around the workpiece.

They are for use on metal.

See [Wikipedia- Tap and die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_and_die) for more detail.

Comment: While metal is quite a bit more common to be used as the material taps and dies (and these dies in particular), it's also possible to use other materials (e.g. wood, plastic, etc.). However, if one is directly using a tap or die on wood (i.e. not a metal insert), one would normally use taps & dies that produce threads appropriate for wood (i.e. much lower turns per inch (TPI) than metal).

Comment: @Makyen - TPI - *turns* per inch - or *threads* per inch?

Comment: @Tim Yep, that's mistyped. It should be threads per inch (TPI). Unfortunately, it's *way* too late for me to edit to fix that or the other grammar issues.

Comment: Didn't realise there was a time limit for edits.

Comment: @Tim Comments can be edited by the user who posted them for 5 minutes. Only moderators can edit comments after that time has expired.